# Как реализовать обход по папкам?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Мне нужно реализовать своего рода собственный проводник по несуществующим папкам (я их задаю из текстового файла). Вот у меня есть список всех папок и для каждой известно в какой папке она находится (или является начальной). Я решил хранить их в списке смежности.
Теперь нужно как-то реализовать рендер и инпут программы. Сейчас в главном цикле вот что имеется:

```
//[C#]
public static void MainLoop() {

    TitleFillUp();
    while (true) {
        DrawLines();
        HandleInput();
    }
}
```

Метод TitleFillUp() заполняет список смежности папок, метод DrawLines() отрисовывает активные папки, а HandleInput() принимает на себя следующие команды с клавиатуры:

- ArrowDown - перейти к следующей папке на этом уровне
- ArrowUp - перейти к предыдущей папке на этом уровне
- ArrowRight - перейти к следующей папке на следующем уровне
- ArrowLeft - перейти к предыдущей папке на предыдущем уровне

Приведу пример графа для нескольких папок. Красным отмечена папка, в которой на данный момент находится пользователь. Граф смешанный.

[image: Пример иерархии папок]

Понятно, что вершины - это папки, а ребра - это возможность перехода из одной папки в другую. Но тут я задался вопросом: **А как собственно отслеживать, где сейчас находится пользователь и как рисовать только открытые ветки папок?**
Для открытых ветвей я думал сделать еще один такой-же список смежности, только не значений, а boolов, а для курсора сделать пару (stage, folder_number). Может это далеко от правды, хотелось бы узнать, как это реализовано в стандартных проводниках?

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Ну заведите себе структуру данных, представляющую собой вершину графа, и держите в нём поле «IsExpanded». На этом пути есть какие-то проблемы?

Comment: Но получается у вершины должно быть тогда 3 состояния: Неактивна, Активна, Выбрана.

Comment: Если даже так, почему бы и нет?

Comment: Ну хорошо, а тогда еще вопрос по этому случаю. Если стрелка вниз должна передвигать на соседнюю папку, а стрелка вправо на уровень выше, то как их различать? Ведь в графе ребра все одинаковые.

Comment: Написал ответ. Раз нужно различать, значит, нужно различать :)

Comment: Придумал как различать, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что обсуждение помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно никто не заморачивается графом смежности, и делает структуру данных наподобие такой (пример на C#, переводится на остальные языки очевидным образом):

```
class Node
{
    List<Node> children;
    bool isExpanded
    bool isVisible;

    void setExpanded (bool value)
    {
        this.isExpanded = value;
        foreach (var child in children)
            child.SetVisible(value); // именно Visible!
    }

    void setVisible (bool value)
    {
        this.isVisible = value;
        foreach (var child in children)
            child.SetVisible(this.isExpanded);
    }
}
```

При этом процедура отрисовки будет, например, такая:

```
void drawSubtree(Node current, int level)
{
    drawNode(current, level);
    foreach (var child in current.children)
    {
        if (child.isVisible)
            drawSubtree(child, level + 1);
    }
}
```